# Send two variables from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send two variables from the php file to the javascript. I've set this up:

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
function cek(user,pass){
    alert("a");
    alert(user);
    alert(pass);


    if(pass!=pass1){
        alert('Password Anda Salah');
    } else if(user==user1){
        alert('Username baru sama dengan username lama');
    }


}
</script>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    $nip=$_REQUEST['nip'];

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE nip=$nip",$koneksi);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $username=$row['username'];
    $password=$row['password'];
    echo'<font face="verdana" size="3" color="black"><br />';

    echo'<form method="post" name="form1">';

    echo'<label>Username </label>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;';

    echo"<input type='text' id='user' name='user' tabindex='1' value=$username> <br />";

    echo'<label>Username Baru</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';

    echo'<input type= "text" id="user1" name="user1" tabindex="2"/> <br />';

    echo'<label>Password</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';

    echo'<input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" tabindex="3" value=$password> <br />';

    echo"<button type='button' name='submit' id='submit' onclick=subtotal(".$username.",\"".$password."\"))>Submit</button>";
    echo'</form>';
    echo'</font>';
?>
```

I've tried to do it this way. But it does not work properly, please help me or give some advice to solve this problem.

Comment: You have this all the wrong way round, you most certainly NEVER want to send the password to the browser even over a secure (https) connection. Once sent it becomes public knowledge and all security is lost

Comment: In fact it should not be in plain text even on your database. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash it before storing it on the database

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :
   in php :

```
 <div id="myid" data-var1="<?php echo $var1;?>"  data-var2="<?php echo $var2;?>">    </div>
```

in jquery :

```
  var var1=$('#myid').attr('data-var1');
  var var2=$('#myid').attr('data-var2');
```

and you can use this variables in javascript function

Comment: See this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719842/send-2-variable-from-php-to-javascript#comment61025416_36719842) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719842/send-2-variable-from-php-to-javascript#comment61025676_36719842)

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = $('#user').val();
var pass = $('#pass').val();
function cek(user,pass) {
 // your script here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a variable from `PHP` to `JavaScript`, You can set the PHP variable to JavaScript variable and the JavaScript variable will be available on your script.

**PHP:**

```
$php_var1='Var_1_Value';
$php_var2='Var_2_Value';

echo "<script>";
echo "var js_var_1 = $php_var1"; //double quote So PHP variable will work in string
echo "var js_var_2 = $php_var2"; 
echo "</script>";
```

Now `js_var_1` and `js_var_2` will be available on your scope and can use:

```
<script>
    alert(js_var_1);
    alert(js_var_2);
</script>
```